# When a multiplicative subgroup of a field generate a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

Is it possible to find a field $F$ of prime characteristic which contains a non-trivial cyclic infinite subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ of $F^\times$ (the multiplicative group of $F$) such that the subring generated by $\langle x\rangle$ in $F$ is a subfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subring generated by $\langle x \rangle$ is contained in ${\mathbb F}_p(x)$. Now $x$ cannot be algebraic over ${\mathbb F}_p$, since otherwise ${\mathbb F}_p(x)$ would be finite and $x$ would have finite order. So $x$ must be transcendental over ${\mathbb F}_p$ and the subring generated is ${\mathbb F}_p[x,x^{-1}]$. But this does not contain $(1+x)^{-1}$, so it is not a field. Hence the answer is no..